# Django url confs won't match

Tags: python, django

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my URL configurations will not point to a page in django.

I am trying to access a URL shown in the error message at the bottom (couldn't get the link to escape, sorry)

YellowOrangeFoxZebra is a valid imgID, defined correctly in the models.

```
imgApp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from imgApp import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<imgID>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
)
```

---

```
views.py

def detail(request, given_image_ID):
image = get_object_or_404(imgAppImage, imgID=given_image_ID)
return render(request, 'imgApp/detail.html', image)
```

---

```
detail.html

<img src="{{ image.imgFile.url }}" >
```

---

The error message I get back out of django is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/imgApp/YellowOrangeFoxZebra/
Using the URLconf defined in thatSite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^imgApp/ ^$ [name='index']
^imgApp/ ^(?P<imgID>\d+)/$ [name='detail']
^imgApp/ ^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$ [name='results']
^imgApp/ ^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
^admin/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, imgApp/YellowOrangeFoxZebra/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Why are you using `\d+`?

Comment: Because it was used in the tutorial, I have no idea what it means. This is my first time with regexes.

Comment: Hey, that gave me a match! Now, I have a type error, "detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'imgID'"

Comment: sorry , i don't know django..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Avinash Raj above for correcting the error in my regex. I've fixed all the issues that popped up in the code after fixing that, a couple type errors, and for posterity have posted the correct versions of the code in question below:

```
imgApp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from imgApp import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<inputID>\w+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
)
```

I swapped the d+ with a w+, and that fixed it! It was looking for digits when it needed to be looking for words.

---

```
views.py

def detail(request, inputID):
    image = get_object_or_404(imgAppImage, imgID=inputID)
    context = {'image': image}
    return render(request, 'imgApp/detail.html', context)
```

I renamed the given_image_ID for clarity to inputID, added the line defining context, and replaced image with context in the render call

---

```
detail.html

<img src="{{ image.imgFile.url }}" >
```

I had this one right! Now however it shows the image it's full size, which unfortunately may be MUCH larger than the window, so that's the next problem to solve!